# python code to reverse an array without using the function

Tags: python, arrays, reverse

My task is to create an empty array and take the input from the user, but I have to print the input element in a reversed order without the function, that too in an array itself.

```
x=int(input('how many cars do you have'))
a=[]
for i in range(x):
    car=(input('enter your car name'))
    a.append(car)
    
    print(a)
y=[]
for i in range(length(a)-1,-1,-1):
    y.append(a[i])
    
    print (y)
```

****Why am i getting repeated reverse array output with this code. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this****

Comment: HiEd's answer is correct. Your `print (y)` is indented, meaning it's in the `if` statement, meaning with every iteration it prints y. So just remove the indentation/four spaces in front of `print (y)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing on any sequence to reverse it :

```py
print(list[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a method from scratch without using any built-in function this one would do

```
arr = [1,2,3,5,6,8]
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
  arr.append(arr[-2-i])
  del(arr[-3-i])
print(arr)
# [8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reverse your list?

```
a = ['car1', 'car2', 'car3']
a.reverse()
print(a)

['car3', 'car2', 'car1']
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use slicing. for example,

```
a = ['1','2','3']
print(a[::-1])
```

will print `['3','2','1']`. I hope this will work for you.

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your code is giving me the correct output except that `len()` is used to calculate the length of a list and not `length()`.

```
x=int(input('how many cars do you have')) 
a=[] 
for i in range(x): 
    car=(input('enter your car name')) 
    a.append(car)
print(a)
y=[] 
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1): 
    y.append(a[i])
print(y)
```

Comment: how many cars do you have3
enter your car nameswift
['swift']
enter your car namebaleno
['swift', 'baleno']
enter your car namebolero
['swift', 'baleno', 'bolero']
['bolero']
['bolero', 'baleno']
['bolero', 'baleno', 'swift'].... i am talking about the third last and second last line.... is it possible to get just the last line.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the output in my answer. I just get ['bolero', 'baleno', 'swift'] as the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Custom way (without using built-in functions) to reverse a list:**

```
def rev_list(mylist):
    max_index = len(mylist) - 1
    return [ mylist[max_index - index] for index in range(len(mylist)) ]
rev_list([1,2,3,4,5])

#Outputs: [5,4,3,2,1]
```